# Swift - How to change background color when a certain amount of points are gained

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been working on a game that when the player gets 10 points the background will change into another color that I put in the string, the same will happen for 20 points, 30 points and so on. My question is how can I make the background fade into different colors when the player gets over 10 points /20 points /30 points. I don't want the colors to be random as I want to put my own color codes/hex values, also I don't want the colors to change when a button is pressed. I just want it to change when the player gets the over a certain amount of points.

A good example of this would be the game "[Don't Touch The Spikes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7t3qfK6mP64)" every 5 points you gain the background fades into a different one.

Note: I made the game in the GameScene and not using the GameViewController as it I made the project into a game file so:

```
import Foundation 
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var movingGround: PPMovingGround!
var hero: PPHero!
var wallGen: PPWallGen!

var isStarted = false
var isGameOver = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    addMovingGround()
    addHero()
    addWallGen()
    addTapToStartLabel()
    addStageLabel()
    addPointsLabels()
    addPhysicsWorld()
    loadHighscore() 
}

func addLevelLabel() {

}

func addMovingGround() {
    movingGround = PPMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view!.frame.width, kMLGroundHeight))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view!.frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(movingGround)
}

func addHero() {
    hero = PPHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(hero)
}

func addWallGen() {
    wallGen = PPWallGen(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view!.frame.size)
    wallGen.position = view!.center
    addChild(wallGen)
}

func addTapToStartLabel() {
    let tapToStartLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Tap to start!")
    tapToStartLabel.name = "tapToStartLabel"
    tapToStartLabel.position.x = view!.center.x
    tapToStartLabel.position.y = view!.center.y + 40
    tapToStartLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    tapToStartLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tapToStartLabel.fontSize = 22.0
    addChild(tapToStartLabel)
    tapToStartLabel.runAction(blinkAnimation())
}

func addStageLabel() {
    let stageLabel = PPStageLabel(num: 1)
    stageLabel.name = "stageLabel"
    stageLabel.position.x = view!.center.x
    stageLabel.position.y = view!.center.y - 120
    stageLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    stageLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    stageLabel.fontSize = 40
    addChild(stageLabel)

    let stageTextLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Stage")
    stageTextLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    stageTextLabel.fontSize = 14.0
    stageTextLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    stageTextLabel.position = CGPointMake(3.0,-15.0)
    stageLabel.addChild(stageTextLabel) }

func addPointsLabels() {
    let pointsLabel = PPPointsLabel(num: 0)
    pointsLabel.name = "pointsLabel"
    pointsLabel.position.x = view!.center.x
    pointsLabel.position.y = view!.center.y + 120
    pointsLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pointsLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    pointsLabel.fontSize = 40
    addChild(pointsLabel)

    let highscoreLabel = PPPointsLabel(num: 0)
    highscoreLabel.name = "highscoreLabel"
    highscoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(view!.frame.size.width - 40, view!.frame.size.height - 30)
    highscoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    highscoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    highscoreLabel.fontSize = 24
    addChild(highscoreLabel)

    let highscoreTextLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Highscore: ")
    highscoreTextLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    highscoreTextLabel.fontSize = 14.0
    highscoreTextLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    highscoreTextLabel.position = CGPointMake(-70.0,3.5)
    highscoreLabel.addChild(highscoreTextLabel)        
}

func addPhysicsWorld() {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}

func loadHighscore() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let highscoreLabel = childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel") as! PPPointsLabel
    highscoreLabel.setTo(defaults.integerForKey("highscore"))
}

// MARK - Game Lifecycle
func start() {
    isStarted = true

    let tapToStartLabel = childNodeWithName("tapToStartLabel")
    tapToStartLabel?.removeFromParent()

    hero.stop()
    movingGround.start()
    wallGen.startGenWallsEvery(1)
}

func gameOver() {
    isGameOver = true

    // everything stops
    hero.fall()
    wallGen.stopWalls()
    movingGround.stop()
    hero.stop()

    // create game over label
    let gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Game Over!")
    gameOverLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    gameOverLabel.position.x = view!.center.x
    gameOverLabel.position.y = view!.center.y + 80
    gameOverLabel.fontSize = 22.0
    addChild(gameOverLabel)
    gameOverLabel.runAction(blinkAnimation())

    // save current points label value
    let pointsLabel = childNodeWithName("pointsLabel") as! PPPointsLabel
    let highscoreLabel = childNodeWithName("highscoreLabel") as! PPPointsLabel
    let stageLabel = childNodeWithName("stageLabel") as! PPStageLabel

    if highscoreLabel.number < pointsLabel.number {
        highscoreLabel.setTo(pointsLabel.number)

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(highscoreLabel.number, forKey: "highscore")
    }
}


func restart() {         
    let newScence = GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
    newScence.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    view!.presentScene(newScence)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if isGameOver {
        restart()
    }else if !isStarted {
        start()
    }else{
        hero.flip()
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if wallGen.wallTrackers.count > 0 {         
        let wall = wallGen.wallTrackers[0] as PPWall         
        let wallLocation = wallGen.convertPoint(wall.position, toNode: self)
        if wallLocation.x < hero.position.x {
            wallGen.wallTrackers.removeAtIndex(0)             
            let pointsLabel = childNodeWithName("pointsLabel") as! PPPointsLabel
            pointsLabel.increment()
        }
    }else if

     wallGen.wallTrackers.count > 0 {
        let wall = wallGen.wallTrackers[0] as PPWall             
        let wallLocation = wallGen.convertPoint(wall.position, toNode: self)
        if wallLocation.x < hero.position.x {
            wallGen.wallTrackers.removeAtIndex(0)                 
            let stageLabel = childNodeWithName("stageLabel") as! PPStageLabel
            stageLabel.increment()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - SKPhysicsContactDelegate
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if !isGameOver {
        gameOver()
    }
}

// MARR: - Animations
func blinkAnimation() -> SKAction {
    let duration = 0.4
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.0, duration: duration)
    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1.0, duration: duration)
    let blink = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, fadeIn])
    return SKAction.repeatActionForever(blink)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't animate SKView.First Declare the variables

```
var isStarted = false
var isGameOver = false
var lastChangedBackground = 0
var background = SKSpriteNode()
```

To do what you want you could add an SKNode as child of your SKScene and let it be the background and create a variable lastChangedBackground in the didMoveToView() function. The lastChangedBackground will let the background change its color only once when it get to a certain value of points.

Then you can add to your update function something like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    //backgroundColor = SKSpriteNode() 
    var background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0),size: view.bounds.size)
    background.position = view.center
    self.addChild(background)

    addMovingGround()
    addHero()
    addWallGen()
    addTapToStartLabel()
    addStageLabel()
    addPointsLabels()
    addPhysicsWorld()
    loadHighscore()
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if wallGen.wallTrackers.count > 0 {

        let wall = wallGen.wallTrackers[0] as PPWall

        let wallLocation = wallGen.convertPoint(wall.position, toNode: self)
        if wallLocation.x < hero.position.x {
            wallGen.wallTrackers.removeAtIndex(0)

            let pointsLabel = childNodeWithName("pointsLabel") as! PPPointsLabel
            pointsLabel.increment()

            //Here points should receive pointsLabel value
            //if pointsLabel.num % 10 == 0 then points is 10, 20, 30...
            if pointsLabel.num % 10 == 0 && pointsLabel.num != lastChangedBackground{
                lastChangedBackground = points
                if (lastChangedBackground == 10) {
                    background.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))
                }
                else if(lastChangedBackground == 20){
                    background.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))
                }
                else if(lastChangedBackground == 30){
                    background.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))
                }
                for wall in wallGen.wallTrackers {
                    wall.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(background.color, colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))
                }

            }
        }
    }else if

     wallGen.wallTrackers.count > 0 {

        let wall = wallGen.wallTrackers[0] as PPWall

        let wallLocation = wallGen.convertPoint(wall.position, toNode: self)
        if wallLocation.x < hero.position.x {
            wallGen.wallTrackers.removeAtIndex(0)

            let stageLabel = childNodeWithName("stageLabel") as! PPStageLabel
            stageLabel.increment()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few errors in here, for example for the "var background = SKSpriteNode(UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0),size: self.size)" it give me an error that 'GameScene ->()-> GameScene' does not have a member named 'size'.

Comment: strange, GameScene is a subclass of SKScene, which has the property size

Comment: try moving the initialization to the didMoveToView method, so:
var background = SKSpriteNode()   //outside
background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0),size: self.size) //inside

Comment: Great! That worked but now there is an error at: self.addSubview background - 1st it tells me that the "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' " after I add that it tells me that the 'Expression resolves to an I-value'? any idea why it does that?

Comment: try replacing that line with 
self.addChild(background)
SKScene doesn't have the addSubview method, its equivalent is addChild, sorry

Comment: Perfect! now the last bit is where

Comment: Perfect! the last problem is ----                                                                       if points % 10 == 0 && points != lastChangedBackground{ ----- am I supposed to replace points with something else or keep it the same and add a variable? as if I change 'points' to 'pointsLabel' it says it could not find an overload for ==. But when I keep it as 'points' it says use of unresolved identifier 'points'. Any clue?

Comment: AMAZING! but when I run it its only in the button left corner of the screen

Comment: what? the new SKSpriteNode?

Comment: yes the whole background is in the left corner, it changes and everything but the other corners are black

Comment: mmm I see... in the initialization of the SKSpriteNode, instead of 
`var background = SKSpriteNode(UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0),size: self.size)` 
replace it with 
`var background = SKSpriteNode(UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0),size: view.bounds.size)`

Comment: instead of view.bounds.size try view.frame.size

Comment: still nothing but the 'view' is supposed to turn purple and its staying black

Comment: it might be because background.position = self.position?

Comment: maybe the background view just isn't where is supposed to be; try replacing the line
`background.position = self.position`
with 
`background.position = view.center`

Comment: Yay! worked, thanks for your time and helping me do this. But if you could tell me how to do the same thing for 20 points and then 30 points and so on will be grate :D

Comment: well, this code was supposed to work with all multiples of 10, because it checks if the remainder of the division by 10 is equal to 0

Comment: for me it only works until 10, as maybe I need to add more colors somewhere?

Comment: what happens if in the line `background.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))` you change the blend factor to 0.1?

Comment: same thing only does it once and does not change back or to a different color

Comment: I updated the answer code adding more colors in the update method

Comment: perfect that is exactly what I wanted :D

Comment: now maybe you can get like 10 colors and when lastChangedBackground hits 100, it goes back to 0, this will guarantee that for every multiple of 10, the background will change its color

Comment: This might be too much I am asking for but is it possible for me to change the walls color? If it takes long don't worry about it, if you can explain it to me in like 5 minutes then please.

Comment: if you want the same effect that the background does, you need to change it the same way, otherwise you can just `wallGen.color = UIColor.redColor()` or any color you want

Comment: `if wall.num % 10 == 0 && wall.num != lastChangedBackground{
                lastChangedBackground = wall
                if (lastChangedBackground == 10) {
                    background.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.blueColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))` --------------------------------------------------------- Would it be like that?

Comment: No,  `wallGen.wallTrackers.count > 0 {

        let wall = wallGen.wallTrackers[0] as PPWall
              background.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(background.color, colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))
        let wallLocation = wallGen.convertPoint(wall.position, toNode: self)
        if wallLocation.x < hero.position.x {
            wallGen.wallTrackers.removeAtIndex(0)

            let stageLabel = childNodeWithName("stageLabel") as! PPStageLabel
            stageLabel.increment()
        }
    }`

Comment: instead of executing the runAction method in background, execute it in the walls, with the background.color as the color parameter

Comment: can you show me an example of that in your code above please?

Comment: did it, not sure if it will work, otherwise you should change the wallGen color

Comment: it kinda works, as if I am going throught he level and I get 10 points then 20 when I get the 20 points the walls will be light purple and the current walls for the 10 are white and the ones I went passed are turning the color I want

Comment: It's because  the line `wallGen.wallTrackers.removeAtIndex(0)` remove the walls, so they can't change color anymore

Comment: 1 last question, for my moving floor flie its only moving at a constant speed but I want it to move faster and faster, any idea how to make that work?

Comment: The moving logic, including the moving speed is probably inside the PPMovingGround class

Comment: yep, but how can I start from slow speed to high speed?

Comment: you need to check if it has the "velocity" property, and set it as you want it